# Golang - race condition using go-routine

Tags: go, race-condition

I tried to use the race flag to my program and issue found :(

The func is the following

```
func (g *WaitingErrorGroup) Start(run func() (bool, error)) {
    g.g.Start(func() {
        requeue, err := run()
        if g.err == nil {
            g.err = err
        }
        if requeue {
            g.requeue = requeue
        }
    })
}
```

The function is called like following

```
g.Start(func() (bool, error) {
    return install(vins, crObjectKey, releasePrefix, kFilePath, objectCli, dependenciesBroadcastingSchema, compStatus)
})

g.Start(func() (bool, error) {
    return false, uninstall(currentRelease, kFilePath, updateChartStatus)
})
```

The stack trace look like following

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0001614a8 by goroutine 82:
  github.vs.sar/agm/coperator/components/tools.(*WaitingErrorGroup).Start.func1()
      /Users/github.vs.sar/agm/coperator/components/tools/waitgroup.go:27 +0x84
  k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.(*Group).Start.func1()
      /Users/i88893/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.22.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:73 +0x6d
```

The start function is this :  **(my code )** `github.vs.sar/agm/coperator/components/tools.(*WaitingErrorGroup).Start.func1()`

```
func (g *WaitingErrorGroup) Start(run func() (bool, error)) {
    g.g.Start(func() {
        requeue, err := run()
        if g.err == nil {
            g.err = err
        }
        if requeue {
            g.requeue = requeue
        }
    })
}
```

The second in the stack trace is this **(not my code)**

`go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.22.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:73 +0x6d`
// Start starts f in a new goroutine in the group.

```
func (g *Group) Start(f func()) {
    g.wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer g.wg.Done()
        f()
    }()
}
```

I guess (not an expert in go) that this is related to the usage of `g.err` from multiple `goroutines` concurrently which isn’t allowed. Same for writing `g.requeue`
Any idea how to solve this?

Maybe I need to use https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex
But not sure how...

**UPDATE**

I took @Danil suggestion (change the lock position) and change it like following
added mutex in the struct and add lock in the function, does it make sense ? Now when I run with race flag everything seems to be OK

```
type WaitingErrorGroup struct {
    g       *wait.Group
    mu      sync.Mutex
    err     error
    requeue bool
}

func (g *WaitingErrorGroup) Start(run func() (bool, error)) {
    g.g.Start(func() {
        g.mu.Lock()
        defer g.mu.Unlock()
        requeue, err := run()
        if g.err == nil {
            g.err = err
        }
        if requeue {
            g.requeue = requeue
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Manipulation of `g.err` is not synchronized. I mean, you can Group.Start any number of functions, each of which would run on a separate goroutine manipulating the state of WaitErrorGroup. All-in-all, the code looks like a contraption. I cannot see the whole picture, but the overall design feel quite unnatural to Go (as if I'd read some Java code).

Comment: @kostix , so I guess the issue is coming from this code `      if g.err == nil {
            g.err = err
        }
        if requeue {
            g.requeue = requeue
        }` am I right?

Comment: Yes. Actually, the answer which had appeared since my comment tells the same. But I'd stress that the overall design appears to me to be a code smell, so I'd concentrace on rethinking the approach. To say this in simpler terms, until you'll have become well-versed in Go concurrency, it helps to use as simple approaches as possible, which means, among other thing, trying to not invent complicated types which hide shared state in them—unless you're absolutely positively cannot live without this. It's better to be explicit about how goroutines interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears because you trying to manipulate not synchronized shared memory (`g.err` in your case) from different goroutines.

You have two different approaches to [handle concurrent code in go](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/concurrency-in-go/9781491941294/ch04.html):

- Synchronization primitives for sharing memory (e.g., sync.Mutex)
- Synchronization via communicating (e.g., channels)

It seems that in your code you follow `Synchronization primitives for sharing memory` and to resolve the error you need to synchronize access to `g.err`.

You can use [sync.Mutex](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex) and [sync.RWMutex](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex)

In your case you will have:

```golang
func (g *WaitingErrorGroup) Start(run func() (bool, error)) {
    g.g.Start(func() {
        requeue, err := run()
        
        // Lock before reading and writing g.err and unlock after
        g.mu.Lock()
        defer g.mu.Unlock()
        
        if g.err == nil {
            g.err = err
        }
        if requeue {
            g.requeue = requeue
        }
    })
}
```

However, according to [Robe Pike more idiomatic way](https://youtu.be/PAAkCSZUG1c?t=163) for Go is `Don't communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating.`(it means use channels, not mutexes). It is already mentioned by @TheFool and @kostix
in the comments.

But it's not clear for me from the question do you have a possibility to redesign your code to follow this idiom.

Comment: thanks, what is `.mu.` object `g.mu.Lock()` , how should I add it ? , when I try your suggestion I got `Unresolved reference 'mu'`

Comment: `mu sync.Mutex`  - field of your `WaitingErrorGroup` structure. You can look at https://gobyexample.com/mutexes as an example

Comment: HI, thanks I tried it out and still I've an issue, any idea, other suggestion?

Comment: Do you have exactly the same problem (with the same trace) or a new one?

Comment: HI, new one but its related to the same code

Comment: but the stack trace is different

Comment: Do you want me to update the question with the new stack trace?

Comment: Could you put it in the comment?)

Comment: when I change the order of your suggestion and use the following `g.g.Start(func() {
  g.mu.Lock()
  defer g.mu.Unlock()
  requeue, err := run()` there is no race condition, but does it make sense to use it like this? I mean put the `lock` before the `run` functions?

Comment: please see my question update

Comment: According to your question in the comments: Yes, looks like it makes sense. It seems that you also use not synchronize shared memory in your `run()` function and `g.mu.Lock()` resolve this problem

Comment: I have updated the answer by providing additional info and links.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a channel to communicate the occurring errors and handle them.

For example, something like this.

```golang
func handleErrors(c chan error) *sync.WaitGroup {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for err := range c {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()
    return &wg
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan error, 2)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    defer handleErrors(c).Wait()
    defer close(c)
    defer wg.Wait()

    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        c <- errors.New("error 1")
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        c <- errors.New("error 2")
    }()

}
```

I think using channels is more idiomatic in go than other sync primitives like locks. Locks are harder to get right, and they can come with performance cost.

If one go routine has the lock, the other goroutines have to wait until the lock is released. So you are introducing a bottleneck in your concurrent execution. In the above example, this is solved by buffering the channel. Even if nothing has read the message yet, still both goroutines are able to pass their message in without being blocked.

Additionally, it can happen that when using a lock, the lock is never released, for example, if the programmer forgot to add the relevant line, leading to a deadlock situation. Although similar bad things can happen when channels are not closed.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/8jr-BkivBSh

Comment: How does it better then waitgroup for my use case can you please elboarte in the answer ?

Comment: @JDC. I have added some info why I think using a channel over a lock is better.

Comment: Thanks, can you please show how I use my code ? I mean the install and uninstall method? what confuse me a bit that you are using tow funcs...

Comment: @JDC I am using 2 function, just to demonstrate that this pattern prevents any race condition, even if you spawn multiple go routines. Because the handle func will pull one value at a time out of the channel, not caring about who sent the message first or when.

Comment: in regard to your code, I don't really get what this is supposed to do, exactly. It looks overcomplicated. I agree with the comments saying this looks like a code smell.